# pointer to an array address minus the address of an array

Tags: arrays, pointers

I have a pointer to array, why it gives me the following output?

```
int main() {
    int b[] = {1, 2};
    cout << "size of int = " << sizeof(int) << endl;
    int *pt = b;
    int i = 0;
    while( i++ < 2) {
        cout << "pt = " << pt << ", b = " << b << endl;
        cout << pt - b << endl;
        (pt)++;
        }
    return 0;
}
```

code output:

```
size of int = 4
pt = 0x7fff576f0c2c, b = 0x7fff576f0c2c
0
pt = 0x7fff576f0c30, b = 0x7fff576f0c2c
1
```

pt is a pointer to the start of array b initially, why pt-b gives me the index of the array that pt points to rather than the index of the array times the size of one element.

Answer (score -1):

it's because your array is really an address, and `int *pt = b;` essentially makes `pt` the exact same as `b`

your output is simply printing the number of times you've incremented `pt` since you set it to `b`

Comment: No, an array is not a pointer.

Comment: Still wrong. An array is not an address.

Answer (score -1):

Remember, in the end, pointers are plain old ints, which represent an *address* in your logical space. Here the address `b` is pointing to remains constant while `pt` gets shifted by one.

Comment: The second part is clearly wrong. It **does** yield the offset in the array.

Comment: @Guillemo No, the **actual array index,** and not the byte offset, as you think. [Read this.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238482/pointer-subtraction-confusion)

Comment: OK, I stand corrected. But just out of curiosity, any way to shift a pointer by bytes rather than by type size? I'm thinking maybe some casting could do the trick, but that code would be nasty.

Comment: I don't think you can do that without invoking UB.