# C++ static_cast from int* to void* to char* - can you help me to understand this code?

Tags: c++, static-cast

I'm a beginner in C++, and I have problem with understanding some code.

I had an exercise to do, to write function which returns size of `int`, and do not use `sizeof()` and `reinterpret_cast`. Someone gave me solution, but I do not understand how it works. Can you please help me to understand it? This is the code:

```
int intSize() {
  int intArray[10];
  int * intPtr1;
  int * intPtr2;

  intPtr1 = &intArray[1];
  intPtr2 = &intArray[2];

  //Why cast int pointer to void pointer?
  void* voidPtr1 = static_cast<void*>(intPtr1);

  //why cast void pointer to char pointer?
  char* charPtr1 = static_cast<char*>(voidPtr1);

  void* voidPtr2 = static_cast<void*>(intPtr2);
  char* charPtr2 = static_cast<char*>(voidPtr2);

  //when I try to print 'charPtr1' there is nothing printed
  //when try to print charPtr2 - charPtr1, there is correct value shown - 4, why?
  return charPtr2 - charPtr1;
}
```

To summarize what I don't understand is, why we have to change `int*` to `void*` and then to `char*` to do this task? And why we have the result when we subtract `charPtr2` and `charPtr1`, but there is nothing shown when try to print only `charPtr1`?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238482/pointer-subtraction-confusion

Comment: `char` is size `1`, so the cast to `char*` is so you can count how many `chars` fit in a single `int`.

Comment: @PeterT The standard requires `char` to be one byte.  (Of course, the implementation gets to choose how many bits in a byte.)

Comment: @JamesKanze ah, you're right. I misremembered it as "at least" 1 byte.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - that depends on how you define `byte`. It's not part of the standard language or library, so you'd have to have a typedef for it.

Comment: @PeteBecker - yes, you're right. The use of `sizeof(char)==1` irks me but I suppose it's the best there is.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - you lost that argument 40 years ago. `<g>`

Comment: Anyone giving such exercises to beginners should learn good C++ style first. These are details that require dirty tricks no one should ever do in production c++ code. Try getting a better teacher.

Answer (score 18):

First of all, never do this in real-world code. You will blow off your leg, look like an idiot and all the cool kids will laugh at you.

That being said, here's how it works:
The basic idea is that the size of an int is equal to the offset between two elements in an int array in bytes. Ints in an array are tightly packed, so the beginning of the second int comes right after the end of the first one:

```
int* intPtr1 = &intArray[0];
int* intPtr2 = &intArray[1];
```

The problem here is that when subtracting two int pointers, you won't get the difference in bytes, but the difference in ints. So `intPtr2 - intPtr1` is `1`, because they are 1 int apart.

But we are in C++, so we can cast pointers to anything! So instead of using int pointers, we copy the value to char pointers, which are 1 byte in size (at least on most platforms).

```
char* charPtr1 = reinterpret_cast<char*>(intPtr1);
char* charPtr2 = reinterpret_cast<char*>(intPtr2);
```

The difference `charPtr2 - charPtr1` is the size in bytes. The pointers still point to the same location as before (i.e. the start of the second and first int in the array), but the difference will now be calculated in sizes of `char`, not in sizes of `int`.

Since the exercise did not allow `reinterpret_cast` you will have to resort to another trick. You cannot `static_cast` from `int*` to `char*` directly. This is C++'s way of protecting you from doing something stupid. The trick is to cast to `void*` first. You can `static_cast` any pointer type to `void*` and from `void*` to any pointer type.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that all answers will be practically useless given the contrived question.

Answer (score 4):

This is the important bit:

```
intPtr1 = &intArray[1];
intPtr2 = &intArray[2];
```

This creates two pointers to adjacent ints in the array. The distance between these two pointers is the size of an integer that you're trying to retrieve. However the way that pointer arithmetic works is that if you subtract these two then the compiler will return you the size in terms of ints, which will always be 1.

So what you're doing next is re-casting these as character pointers. Characters are (or de-facto are) 1 byte each, so the difference between these two pointers as character pointers will give you an answer in bytes. That's why you're casting to character pointers and subtracting.

As for via `void*` - this is to avoid having to use `reinterpret_cast`. You're not allowed to cast directly from a `int*` to a `char*` with `static_cast<>`, but going via `void*` removes this restriction since the compiler no longer knows it started with an `int*`. You could also just use a C-style cast instead, `(char*)(intPtr1)`.

Comment: I get "invalid static_cast from type ‘int*’ to type ‘char*’" when static casting directly to char*, so it appears it's not allowed.

Comment: Yes, I've just tried it myself now. That's what the restriction on `reinterpret_cast<>` in the question is for I see now!

Comment: Yup: static_cast from int* to char* is not allowed. Need to go via void*. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

"do not use sizeof() and reinterpret_cast"... nothing's said about std::numeric_limits, so you could do it like that :)

```
#include <limits>

int intSize()
{
   // digits returns non-sign bits, so add 1 and divide by 8 (bits in a byte)
   return (std::numeric_limits<int>::digits+1)/8;
}
```

Comment: Cute, but the standard doesn't say that `int` has to be efficiently stored.  They could make `sizeof(int)` be 100, but only have 15 binary digits of precision.

Comment: Wouldn't this break on a really obscure architecture; binary coded decimal for example?

Comment: @Yakk According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/digits) at least, `nl<int>::digits` is *defined* as `CHAR_BIT*sizeof(int)-1` (though I haven’t checked it).

Comment: @KonradRudolph aww, and there goes my trick. So it IS using sizeof() behind the curtain..

Comment: @Alex1985 It’s *defined* that way, that doesn’t mean it’s *implemented* that way. And in fact the other methods *also* use `sizeof` behind the curtains, so you’re safe (somebody, either Stroustrup or Meyers, cite this as the reason that `sizeof` cannot be overloaded, because pointer arithmetic uses it internally).

Comment: @KonradRudolph that would be a horrible definition on a system that uses binary coded decimal to store its `int`s...  Then again, I am not sure what wouldn't be a horrible definition of "number of binary bits of precision" on such a system, or how `nl<int>::digits` would be useful on such a system!

Comment: @Yakk I’m too lazy to look it up in the standard, but BCD is generally badly supported in C++11. For instance, two’s complement encoding is required at least in some specific instances (such as the requirement that assigning `-1` to an unsigned type must set all its bits).

Answer (score 1):

Please read this: richly commented.

```
int intSize()
{
    int intArray[2]; // Allocate two elements. We don't need any more than that.

    /*intPtr1 and intPtr2 point to the addresses of the zeroth and first array elements*/
    int* intPtr1 = &intArray[0]; // Arrays in C++ are zero based
    int* intPtr2 = &intArray[1];

    /*Note that intPtr2 - intPtr1 measures the distance in memory 
      between the array elements in units of int*/

    /*What we want to do is measure that distance in units of char;
      i.e. in bytes since once char is one byte*/

    /*The trick is to cast from int* to char*. In c++ you need to 
      do this via void* if you are not allowed to use reinterpret_cast*/

     void* voidPtr1 = static_cast<void*>(intPtr1);
     char* charPtr1 = static_cast<char*>(voidPtr1);

     void* voidPtr2 = static_cast<void*>(intPtr2);
     char* charPtr2 = static_cast<char*>(voidPtr2);

    /*The distance in memory will now be measure in units of char; 
      that's how pointer arithmetic works*/
    /*Since the original array is a contiguous memory block, the 
      distance will be the size of each element, i.e. sizeof(int) */
     return charPtr2 - charPtr1;
}
```

Comment: You don't even need two elements, one will suffice.  And you don't need all of the intervening `static_cast`; using `reinterpret_cast` to go directly from `int*` to `char*` will work.  And you really don't need any of this, since the results are guaranteed to be equal to `sizeof( int )`.

Comment: @James Kanze, one of the many contrivances of the question is that you are not allowed to use reinterpret_cast. So I have to use static_cast. An indeed the result will be sizeof(int).

Answer (score 1):

Pointer subtraction in C++ gives the number of elements between
the pointed to objects.  In other words, `intPtr2 - intPtr1`
would return the number of `int` between these two pointers.
The program wants to know the number of bytes (`char`), so it
converts the `int*` to `char*`.  Apparently, the author doesn't
want to use `reinterpret_cast` either.  And `static_cast` will
not allow a direct convertion from `int*` to `char*`, so he
goes through `void*` (which is allowed).

Having said all that: judging from the name of the function and
how the pointers are actually initialized, a much simpler
implementation of this would be:

```
int
intSize()
{
    return sizeof( int );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is actually no need to convert to `void*`, other than avoiding `reinterpret_cast`.

Converting from a pointer-to-`int` to a pointer-to-`char` can be done in one step with a `reinterpret_cast`, or a C-style cast (which, by the standard, ends up doing a `reinterpret_cast`).  You could do a C-style cast directly, but as that (by the standard) *is* a `reinterpret_cast` in that context, you'd violate the requirements.  Very tricky!

However, you can convert from an `int*` to a `char*` through the `void*` intermediary using only `static_cast`.  This is a small hole in the C++ type system -- you are doing a two-step `reinterpret_cast` without ever calling it -- because `void*` conversion is given special permission to be done via `static_cast`.

So all of the `void*` stuff is just to avoid the `reinterpret_cast` requirement, and would be silly to do in real code -- being aware you can do it might help understanding when someone did it *accidentally* in code (ie, your `int*` appears to be pointing at a string: how did that happen?  Well, someone must have gone through a hole in the type system.  Either a C-style cast (and hence a `reinterpret_cast`), or it must have round-tripped through `void*` via `static_cast`).

If we ignore that gymnastics, we now have an array of `int`.  We take pointers to adjacent elements.  In C++, arrays are packed, with the difference between adjacent elements equal to the `sizeof` the elements.

We then convert those pointers to pointers-to-`char`, because we know (by the standard) that `sizeof(char)==1`.  We subtract these `char` pointers, as that tells us how many multiples-of-`sizeof(char)` there are between them (if we subtract `int` pointers, we get how many multiples-of-`sizeof(int)` there are between them), which ends up being the size of the `int`.

If we try to print `charPtr1` through `std::cout`, `std::cout` assumes that our `char*` is a pointer-to-`\0`-terminated-buffer-of-`char`, due to C/C++ convention.  The first `char` pointed to is `\0`, so `std::cout` prints nothing.  If we wanted to print the pointer value of the `char*`, we'd have to cast it to something like `void*` (maybe via `static_cast<void*>(p)`).