# C and pointers operation problems

Tags: c, pointers

the following C program

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>

#define A 1
#define B 1

int main(){
    int a[A], b[B];
    ptrdiff_t delta;


    printf("%p    %p",&a+A,&b);
    delta=&a+A-&b;
    printf("\n* %td *\n",delta);

    if ((&a+A)==&b) printf("\n==1.1");
    if ((&a+A)-&b==0) printf("\n==1.2");
    if (&a==&a) printf("\n==2");

    return 0;
}
```

---

produces this result:

```
0x7fff107d5454    0x7fff107d5440
* 5 *

==2
```

Can you explain me ehy `0x7fff107d5454-0x7fff107d5440=5`?

Comment: `&a` is a `int (*)[A]`, i.e., a pointer to array of size `A`, not a pointer to int.  Arrays decay to a pointer to their first element, so `a + A` or `&a[0] + A` are equivalent and would increment by `A * sizeof(int)`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pointer subtraction confusion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238482/pointer-subtraction-confusion)

Answer (score 2):

This is pointer arithmetic. Strictly, 0x7fff107d5454  -  0x7fff107d5440 is 0x14, which is 20 decimal. In pointer arithmetic the actual difference is divided by the sizeof the base pointer type, which is in this case 4 for integers (on your system). So you get 5.