# How exactly pointer subtraction works in case of integer array?

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int arr[] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60};
    int *ptr1 = arr;
    int *ptr2 = arr + 5;
    printf("Number of elements between two pointer are: %d.", 
                                (ptr2 - ptr1));
    printf("Number of bytes between two pointers are: %d",  
                              (char*)ptr2 - (char*) ptr1);
    return 0;
}
```

For the first `printf()` statement the output will be `5` according to [Pointer subtraction confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238482/pointer-subtraction-confusion)

What about the second `printf()` statement, what will be the output?

Comment: Simple...run and check...

Comment: Got 20 as output, but how?

Comment: Have you read the answer to the question you referred to? Think about it that way: when you add +5 to a pointer to an int, it advances 5 ints in size in memory. How many chars worth of memory is that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To quote `C11`, chapter §6.5.6, *Additive operators*

> When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object; the result is the difference of the subscripts of the two array elements.

So, when you're doing

```
printf("Number of elements between two pointer are: %d.", 
                            (ptr2 - ptr1));
```

both `ptr1` and `ptr2` are pointers to `int`, hence they are giving the difference in subscript, 5. In other words, the difference of the address is counted in reference to the `sizeof(<type>)`.

OTOH,

```
 printf("Number of bytes between two pointers are: %d",  
                          (char*)ptr2 - (char*) ptr1);
```

both `ptr1` and `ptr2` are *casted* to a pointer to `char`, which has a size of 1 byte. The calculation takes place accordingly. Result: `20`.

**FWIW**, please note, the subtraction of two pointers produces the result as type of `ptrdiff_t` and you should be using `%td` format specifier to print the result.

Comment: wow, Joachim and you answering the same question. There's an unholy aggregation of points here :)

Comment: Didn't know about `%td`. Neat !

Comment: @SouravGhosh: It's just cool to see the both of you answer within the same minute with quite a complex answer  -- gives you the feeling there's a very solid base of competence on SO :)

Answer (score 5):

If you have two pointers of type `T` that point to elements of the same array then the difference of the pointers yields the number of elements of type `T` between these pointers

So the first output statement

```
printf("Number of elements between two pointer are: %d.", 
                            (ptr2 - ptr1));
```

outputs 5 - the number of elements of type `int` between pointers `ptr1` and `ptr2`.

It is the so-called pointer arithmetic.

Pointers `(char*)ptr1` and `(char*)ptr2` have the same values as the original pointers `ptr1` and `ptr2` but they consider (reinterpret) the memory extent as an array of type `char` each element of which has size equal to `sizeof( char )`. In C `sizeof( char )` is always equal to 1.
Thus the difference `( char * )ptr2 - ( char * ) ptr1` gives the number of elements of type `char` that can fit the memory extent. It is evident that 
`sizeof( char )` is not greater than `sizeof( int )`. So the same memory extent can accomodate more elements of type `char` than of type `int`. If for example `sizeof( int )` is equal to `4` then the memory extent can accomodate `5 * sizeof( int )` elements of type `char` that is `20`.

Answer (score 4):

Pointer arithmetics is always in the units of the base type.

In your case you have

```
int *ptr1 = ...
```

Then doing `ptr1 + 5` will add `sizeof(*ptr1) * 5` *bytes* to the pointer `ptr1`. Considering that `sizeof(*ptr1)` (which is the same as `sizeof(int)`) is `4`, then you get `4 * 5` which equals `20` bytes.

Answer (score 4):

Each array element is an `int` and there are `5` elements between both the pointers. Thus there will be `5*sizeof(int)` amount of bytes in between both the pointers.