# What is happening with this arithmetic expression involving pointers?

Tags: c, pointers

Here is the code in C:

```
#define ALLOCSIZE 1000 /* size of available space */

static char allocbuf[ALLOCSIZE]; /* storage for alloc */
static char *allocp = allocbuf; /* next free position */

char *alloc(int n) /* return pointer to n characters */
{
    if (allocbuf + ALLOCSIZE - allocp >= n) { /* it fits */
        ...
    }
}
```

I don't understand what is happening in the following expression:

```
allocbuf + ALLOCSIZE - allocp >= n
```

I know allocbuf as an array name is equivalent to a pointer to the first element &allocbuf[0], and obviously allocp is a pointer, and finally that ALLOCSIZE is a simple int. So adding ALLOCSIZE to allocbuff gives the ALLOCSIZE indexed element of allocbuff which is also a pointer. But subtracting the pointer allocp from pointer &allocbuf[ALLOCSIZE] is where I am lost. I am not even sure one can add pointers in C.

Please tell me where I am wrong or what I am missing in this interpretation.

The point of this program is to store characters.

Comment: You cannot add pointers, but you can subtract them to get the distance (in # of objects). Think `allocbuf + ALLOCSIZE - allocbuf`. The result is as expected - `ALLOCSIZE`.

Comment: The difference of two pointers `b - a` is the number of elements between `a` and `b`. So, `allocbuf - allocp` is `-1` times the number of elements already allocated.

Comment: That `if` is the same as `if (ALLOCSIZE >= n)`. Pointers can't be added as it makes no sense. However, it can be subtracted. (Google 'subtract pointers c' for more information on this)

Comment: @CoolGuy given that `allocp` never changes, yes, but that is probably a bad assumption.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The code is a fixed-buffer allocator, and is checking to make sure you have at least `n` bytes left. It helps to view things pictorially, and by pictorially I mean with MSPaint:

[image: allocator]

So breaking down the expression:

```
allocbuf + ALLOCSIZE - allocp >= n
```

`allocbuf + ALLOCSIZE` is the end of the array. The difference between the end and `allocp` is the remaining bytes. So we just check to make sure that difference is at least `n`.

Subtracting two pointers, as long as they point to elements within the same array (or one-past-the-end), is well-defined as the number of elements between them. As a simpler example, `allocbuf` and `allocbuf + ALLOCSIZE` are both pointers (of type `char*`), and `(allocbuf + ALLOCSIZE) - allocbuf == ALLOCSIZE`, the number of elements (of type `char`, in this case) between them.

Answer (score 7):

Subtracting pointer from pointer will give you (if they are compatible) number of elements (size is determined by the type the pointers point to) between them.

So:

```
allocbuf + ALLOCSIZE
```

pointer pointing after the last element of allocbuf

```
allocbuf + ALLOCSIZE - allocp
```

amount of elements left between last element of allcobuf (+ 1) and allocp

In which case:

```
allocbuf + ALLOCSIZE - allocp >= n
```

determines if enough elements are left in `allocbuf` to fit `n` elements.

Edit:

You can compare it to arrays:
If you have pointer to first element (which would be indexed with `0`) and second pointer, which points 4 times the size of element further (which would point to 5th element indexed with 4), then when you are subtracting these two you will get 4 elements between them (like subtracting index 0 from index 4). But it only makes sense, when pointers point to the same buffer of memory (like in arrays).

So this:

```
int array[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
int a* = &array[0] //equivalent to array
int b* = &array[4]
```

and this:

```
int *array = malloc(6 * sizeof(int));
//set array values
int *a = array;
int *b = array + 5;
```

Is (almost) the same.

Comment: OK this makes sense. Is there some logic or intuition behind subtracting two pointers of same type and obtaining distance between them? Edit: never mind I found a lot of answers on google (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238482/pointer-subtraction-confusion)

Comment: Well, yeah. Pointers can be translated to indexes in arrays. So if one pointer points to first element (indexed with 0) and other one points to 4 times the size of element further from the first one (being the equivalent of 5th element in an array - indexed with 4), then by extracting them you will know, there are 4 elements between them (like substracting: 4 - 0 ).

Comment: Ah is it like *(a+i)-*(a+j) = i-j. that would make sense intuitively.

Comment: well, without these asterisk - yeah.

Answer (score 4):

The expression `allocbuf + ALLOCSIZE - allocp` will give the number of elements in between pointers `&allocbuf[ALLOCSIZE]` and pointer `allocp`.
`allocbuf + ALLOCSIZE - allocp >= n` simply checks whether `n` is less than that of elements in between pointers `&allocbuf[ALLOCSIZE]` and `allocp` or not.

Note that

#### C11: 6.5.6 Additive operators (p9):

> **When two pointers are subtracted**, both shall point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object; **the result is the difference of the subscripts of the two array elements**. [...].
> In other words, if the expressions `P` and `Q` point to, respectively, the `i`-th and `j`-th elements of an array object, **the expression `(P)-(Q)` has the value `i−j`** provided the value fits in an object of type `ptrdiff_t`.

Comment: only in first run. If allocp is incremented by n inside alloc function, then this will not be accurate in next call of alloc function.

Comment: @zoska; I am not sure about that. Snippet does not explains much.

Comment: @haccks yeah, but there would be no point of having allocp if it wasn't so

Answer (score 1):

> I am not even sure one can add pointers in C.

Subtracting two pointers returns the distance between them: the number of elements between them (not the size in bytes or anything else).

This sub-expression, as you said, first goes one past the last element:

```
allocbuf + ALLOCSIZE
```

Then, by subtracting `allocp`, it returns the distance between this one-past-the-last-element pointer, and the next free position stored in `allocp`

```
(allocbuf + ALLOCSIZE) - allocp
```

If this distance is superior to n, it means there is still room for at least n more elements in allocbuf.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, think of `allocbuf` and `allocp` as numbers:

Now, we do not know which number, but lets say we know that `allocp'' points to some element of`allocbuf``.

Then, `allocp - allocbuf` is the index of the element that `allocp` is pointing to (remember, think of them as numbers - at least as long as they point to the same memory object).

So in conclusion, `allocbuf + ALLOCSIZE - allocp` is `ALLOCSIZE - "the index of allocbuf that allocp is pointing to"`.
In other words, the number of leftover elements.

The condition then checks if there are enough leftover elements.

Answer (score 1):

```
allocbuf + ALLOCSIZE - allocp >= n
```

Can be expanded to

```
(allocbuf + ALLOCSIZE) - allocp >= n
```

To show what is happening.

`(allocbuf + ALLOCSIZE)` returns a pointer `ALLOCSIZE` elements in memory after wherever `allocbuf` points. For example, as `allocbuf` points to the first element, and `ALLOCSIZE` is 1000, the operation returns the element (pointer) 1000 elements after `allocbuf` (this is actually undefined memory; it is one element after the last allocated element, so undefined behaviour would occur if this pointer were to be dereferenced).

Once `(allocbuf + ALLOCSIZE)` has been deduced, once the pointer `allocp` has been taken from it, it will return a type like `size_t` (unsigned), which gives the amount of elements between `(allocbuf + ALLOCSIZE)` and `allocp`. For example, if `allocp` pointed to the 403rd element, and someone wanted to allocate 637 elements from the function alloc, it would do the following:

`allocbuf + ALLOCSIZE - allocp` - get the amount of spare elements

`allocbuf + ALLOCSIZE - allocp >= n` see if it is larger than or equal to n. If so, it can allocate.