# C++ Pointers: Address - Address Confusion

Tags: c++, pointers

I am trying to understand pointer arithmetic in C++ but I just don't get it why the below code gives a weird output which I cannot comprehend.

```
using namespace std;

int main() {
int *p1, *p2;
int x = 100;
int y = 200;
p1 = new int;
p2 = new int;

*p1 = 100;
*p2 = 200;

    cout<<p1<<endl;
    cout<<p2<<endl;

    cout<<p2 - p1<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This gives an output as follows:

```
0x7fffd46d2e70

0x7fffd46d2e90

8
```

I do not understand how come p2 - p1 is 8. Which I believe is the size of the pointer. But shouldn't it be 20?? (as calculated below)

0x7fffd46d2e90 - 0x7fffd46d2e70 = 20

or 20 / 2 = 10??

Hope I can get this cleared and some more explanation on pointer arithmetic. Specifically when we subtract an address from another address

Comment: An int has sizeof(4), 0x20 / 4 is 8.

Comment: Firstly, you need to learn the difference between decimal and hexadecimal. Secondly...

Comment: duplicate of [Pointer subtraction confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238482/pointer-subtraction-confusion)

Comment: Shockingly bad duplicate. Different language for starters. Plus this one is about the difference between two pointers that are not in the same array. The behaviour of the code in this question is undefined.

Comment: This code was in the Algorithms and Data structures notes